# Make the detection of points in shapefile polygon faster in R

Tags: r, optimization, shapefile

I have a code written in R to detect the amount of water between villages (or points in shapefile polygon). I am creating an undirected graph of over 2379 villages (villages have numerical names), so that would bring it 2.8 billion combinations. The graph is just a dataframe. I have the coordinates of each Village:

```
VillageName1, VillageName2
Village1, Village2
Village1, Village3
Village1, Village4
...
Village2379, Village2378
```

For every combination, I have a function that will create points from, say, Village1 to Village2 in 100meter intervals. So if Village1 and Village2 are 1km apart, 8 points will be created. This function runs relatively fast.

The problem is that I am using a World Ocean shapefile (6.9mb) so that I can detect the amount of water in 100meters if Village1 and Village2 are on two separate islands, but it's very slow (approx 4seconds per calculation) and running it 2.8 billion times will take forever.

I have tried filtering the shapefile (ocean_indo_shapefile) to the country based on those villages (Indonesia):

```
sea <- readOGR('World_EEZ_v8_2014.shp')
ocean_indo_shapefile <- sea[sea$Country == "Indonesia", ]

#this function creates the points from Village1 to Village2 in 100m intevals, output is a dataframe
points <- create_coordinates(village1_lat, village1_long, village2_lat, village2_long, 0.1)

coordinates(points) <- ~ Longitude + Latitude
proj4string(points) <- proj4string(ocean_indo_shapefile)
#the calculation below is slow
water_in_meter <- length(points[ocean_indo_shapefile,])
```

I am not sure if anyone can help suggest on how I could make this a lot faster, I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: postgis might be the way to go

Comment: Only the last line is slow? `points` is a data frame?

Comment: I have never used PostGIS before so I am not sure how to go by doing so in this context.

Comment: Yes points is a dataframe and the last line is the slow one, previous functions are very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to make use of the `%over%` function from `sp`.  It should be able to indicate, relatively quickly, which points fall in bodies of water (presuming that's what your shapefile indicates). You'll just have some data munging to do afterwards to get the village-by-village counts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Jul, it did improve the performance but only slightly.

Comment: If you can upload a sample of your data, I can try testing some approaches